# How to read and parse consecutive, very large JSON objects from a file (or a filestream) using node.js' fs module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Is there any "best practice" approach to read consecutive JSON objects from a file using nodejs' fs module, e.g., by reading from a filestream.

I am aware that, in principle, I could read the entire file into a buffer and parse it with JSON.parse. But in my case, the binary information of each JSON object (e.g., base64 images) can be very large. JSON.parse might not work because of memory constraints. Is there a way to parse object by object from (say) a filestream?

This is how my file might look like. "***" stands for a huge amount of binary base64-encoded data.

```
{
  "thumbnailImage":"data:image/jpeg;base64***",
  "highResolutionImage":"data:image/jpeg;base64***",
  "pageNumber":1,
  "documentId":"..."
  ...
}
{
  "thumbnailImage":"data:image/jpeg;base64***",
  "highResolutionImage":"data:image/jpeg;base64***",
  "pageNumber":2,
  "documentId":"..."
  ...
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Google "JSON lines", which is a format involving complete JSON strings that occupy a single line of text (that is, the JSON string has no newlines in it; the newlines in the file separate complete JSON strings).

Comment: Thank you very much for your immediate response! The "JSON lines" approach works perfectly well. In order to potentially also help others, here is what I have done specifically: I use the nodejs module "readline". I save my file with nodejs' fs module (with the "standard" writestream function) and I put a "newline character" after each JSON object, hence applying the "JSON lines" approach. Afterwards, I use the readline module to deserialize my JSON objects.

Comment: PS: I would like to close my question (as it has been answered). However, I did not manage to do so.